# Are there any characters that don't work for _GET variables in a browser?

Tags: php, html, url, get

This is a little out of the blue and it's mostly curiosity. I hope it's not a waste pf time and space.
I was writing a little script to validate accounts with a link so I decided to send an email with a link to the php script and in the link I would put two variables to get with the _GET array. A key and the email. Then I would just search the database with that email and key and change it's activated status to true... No prob. Easy enough even though it may not be very elegant..

I used a script for the generation of the key that I used elsewhere in the site for generating a new password (to reset it for instance) but sometimes it didn't work and after a lot of tries I noticed (and I felt stupid then) that the array my password generation function drew from was this:

> '0123456789_!@#$%&*()-=+abcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

So naturally I deleted the & character that is used for separating variables in the url... Then in another try I noticed that the link in the email was not recognized whole and stopped after the '#' character as well which I then remembered is used for references in an html so I deleted that as well. In the end I decided to leave only alphanumeric characters to be sure but I am curious; Are ther any more characters that are not 'valid' for url's using utilizing _GET and is there any way to use those characters anyway (maybe ulr encode or somwething)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of characters that are invalid. Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to convert them to URL safe encodings. (Always run that function over any *data* you are inserting into a URL).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `urlencode()` before sending the values to `$_GET`.

Comment: **Don't** use `urldecode`. The data will be decoded before it is put into `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `url_encode` and `url_decode` but I would stay away from `& # ?` these are normal URL characters.

Also when it comes to passwords : dont stress about an algorithm, use `sha1` `crypt` or something along those lines with a `salt`. These algorithms will be much stronger than your homemade ones.

Comment: **Don't** use `urldecode`. The data will be decoded before it is put into `$_GET`. There is nothing wrong with using `&`, `#` or `?` in data. `urldecode` will encode them for transport in URLs.

Comment: I mean't use it later if he would like. i guess i should have been clearer with that. Also there is nothing wrong with those characters, but I'd stay away from those in passwords (personal choice)

Comment: Don't use `sha1`, it is a [weak algorithum](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Insecure_Cryptographic_Storage). `crypt` is a function that maps onto a bunch of different algorithms, use a cryptographically strong one.

Comment: No, I use sha1 for now because that is what mysql supports (well the version the hosting site has anyway) but those passwords I make are just for when resetting a password.. I.E someone forgot their password, can't sent the sha1 in mysql so send a new password to log in and then change it to what they want...